# Integrating the Associated Legendre Polynomials

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, polynomials

I know the following identity:

$\qquad \int_{-1}^1 P_l^m(t)^2dt=\frac{2(m+n)!}{(2n+1)(n-m)!}$

I would like to verify this result using Mathematica. This is what I entered:

```
Integrate[LegendreP[l, m, t]^2, {t, -1, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> (m | l) ∈ Integers && l >= 0 && -l <= m <= l]
```

However it did not give the result I wanted. Any tips or advice would be appreciated!

Comment: There are problems with your formulation. In your statement of the identity you have `m` and `l` on the lhs and `m` and `n` on the rhs. In your code you call `LegendreP` with 4 arguments, but it at most takes 3. You put constraints on `m` but none on `l`.

Comment: @m_goldberg I have made the necessary amendments but I still did not get the result. Am I missing out some important constraints?

Comment: It is entirely possible that Mathematica can not carry out the integration.

Comment: Your equation has $m$ and $l$ on the lhs but $m$ and $n$ on the rhs.

Comment: Numerically, `With[{nmax = 25},
 And @@ (Table[
     Integrate[LegendreP[n, m, t]^2, {t, -1, 1}] ==
      2 (m + n)!/((2 n + 1) (n - m)!),
     {n, 0, nmax}, {m, -n, n}] // Flatten)]` evaluates to `True`. Increase `nmax` until you lose patience.

Comment: Just to add an anecdote to @BobHanlon's contribution, I needed a similar `LegendreP` integration (although a little bit more complex), had a general formula that I derived by testing a few cases, but couldn't get Mathematica to confirm it for all `l` and `m` (which may have been lacking knowledge on my part). If you need it for something scientific, often there's an upper bound for what you need to confirm it for. In my case that was ~41, so I just confirmed it up to 100. It's effective and quick.

Comment: Replacing `LegendreP[l, m, t]` by its (finite) series expansion and integrating should work, although that seems like a cumbersome approach.