# How to check whether Laguerre polynomials are orthogonal?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, polynomials, homework

I've got the problem with checking if Laguerre polynomials for n=1,...,10 are orthogonal.

I have to create the list of these polynomials, then create the matrix of integrals from 0 to infinity. Something like:

```
M=Integrate[LaguerreL[i,x] LaguerreL[j,x] Exp[-x], {x,0,Infinity}]
```

And in the end I have to draw the dynamic drawing of these polynomials so that if I choose on graph n, from 0 to 20, the correct polynomial will be drawn with its derivative.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155030/integrate-squared-legendre-polynomial

Comment: `Table[M, {i, 10}, {j, 10}]`?

Comment: I have to integrate by exp(-x)dx instead of dx.

Comment: That's not the problem....

Answer (score 7):

```
Integrate[LaguerreL[i, x] LaguerreL[j, x] Exp[-x], {x, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> Element[{i, j}, Integers] && j > i > 0]
```

> 0

```
n = 10;
Outer[Integrate[LaguerreL[#, x] LaguerreL[#2, x] Exp[-x], {x, 0, ∞}] &, 
  Range[n], Range[n]] == IdentityMatrix[n]
```

> True

```
Manipulate[Show[Plot[Evaluate@LaguerreL[Sort@n, x], {x, 0, 10}, 
   PlotLegends -> ("LaguerreL[" <> ToString[#] <> ", x]" & /@ Sort[n]), 
   PlotRange -> {-15, 15}], 
  Plot[Evaluate[D[LaguerreL[Sort@n, z], z] /. z -> x], {x, 0, 10}, 
   PlotLegends -> ("D[LaguerreL[" <> ToString[#] <> ", x], x]" & /@ Sort[n]), 
   PlotStyle -> Dashed]],
 {{n, {5, 10, 17}}, Range[0,20], TogglerBar}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
Table[
 NIntegrate[LaguerreL[i, x] LaguerreL[j, x] Exp[-x], {x, 0, Infinity}],
 {i, 10},
 {j, 10}
] // Chop // Quiet
MatrixForm@%
Manipulate[
 Plot[
  {#, D[#, x]} &@LaguerreL[n, x] // Evaluate,
  {x, 0, 10},
  Frame -> True,
  BaseStyle -> {11, FontFamily -> Times},
  PlotLabel -> StringForm["n=``", n]
 ],
{n, 0, 20, 1, PopupMenu}
]
```

> {{1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0,
>      0, 1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
>     0, 0, 0, 1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1., 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
>      0, 0, 0, 0, 1., 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1., 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
>     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1., 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.}}

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 1. & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1. & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1. & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1. & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1. & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1. & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1. & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1. & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1. & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1. \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: Thank you! :) Can this graph be simply modified? For example, when I increase n, on the graph will be shown graphs 1,2,3 to n, all of them on one graph?

Comment: @Crunchy Sure, just change `Plot[{#, D[#, x]} &@LaguerreL[n, x]` to `Plot[{#, D[#, x]} &@LaguerreL[Range[0, n], x]`.  Though, it starts to look a little chaotic even at n=4.  At that point, I would go with @kglr's implementation.